# Android Lottie Build.gradle issue

Tags: android, build.gradle, lottie

After adding lottie to build.gradle file saying Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're including maven repo in your root `build.gradle` e.g.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```